# Trying to draw a 3D plot but for some reason is not plotting anything

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a 3d plot but for some reason the plot is not showing. I am a complete beginner, and this the code:

```
 f[s_, r_, theta_] := 
  Sqrt[2]*s*Sin[phi] + Sqrt[3]*r*Sin[theta + Pi/3] + 
   r*Cos[Pi/3]*Sin[phi] - Sqrt[6]*c*Cos[phi];
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[
  f[s, r, theta], {s, -200, 200}, {r, -200, 200}, {theta, -Pi/2, 
   Pi/2}],
 {{phi, 30, "phi"}, 0, 90, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c, 0, "C"}, 0, 100, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I suggest moving  all parameters to the arguments of `f`: `Clear[f]; f[s_, r_, theta_, phi_, c_] := Sqrt[2]*s*Sin[phi] + Sqrt[3]*r*Sin[theta + Pi/3] + r*Cos[Pi/3]*Sin[phi] - Sqrt[6]*c*Cos[phi];` and then `ContourPlot3D[f[s, r, theta, phi, c], ...]`.